# Opening a custom DropDown with the DropDown open() method does not work

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I do define in the kv file a basic custom DropDown. The app GUI is very simple, with a button bar a  the top and a TextInput consuming the rest of the screen. Here's the code:

dropdowntrialgui.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    pass

class DropDownTrialGUI(BoxLayout):
    dropD = CustomDropDown()

    def openMenu(self, widget):
        self.dropD.open(widget)


class DropDownTrialGUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DropDownTrialGUI()


if __name__== '__main__':
    dbApp = DropDownTrialGUIApp()

    dbApp.run()
```

and the kv file:

dropdowntrialgui.kv

```
DropDownTrialGUI:

    <CustomDropDown>
        Button:
            text: 'My first Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '28dp'
            on_release: root.select('item1')
        Button:
            text: 'My second Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '28dp'
            on_release: root.select('item2')

    <DropDownTrialGUI>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "28dp"
            Button:
                id: toggleHistoryBtn
                text: "History"
                size_hint_x: 15
            Button:
                id: deleteBtn
                text: "Delete"
                size_hint_x: 15
            Button:
                id: replaceBtn
                text: "Replace"
                size_hint_x: 15
            Button:
                id: replayAllBtn
                text: "Replay All"
                size_hint_x: 15
            Button:
                id: menuBtn
                text: "..."
                size_hint_x: 15
                on_press: root.openMenu(self)

        TextInput:
            id: readOnlyLog
            size_hint_y: 1
            readonly: True
```

Pressing the menuBtn has no effect. How can I fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing the class correctly, as a general rule you shouldn't define anything as a class attribute (except for the kivy properties), instead define the widgets as instance attributes by instantiating them in the `__init__` method:

```
class DropDownTrialGUI(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DropDownTrialGUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropD = CustomDropDown()

    def openMenu(self, widget):
        self.dropD.open(widget)
```

[image]